# Give an example of group $G$ and a subset closed under multiplication but not a subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Give an example of a group $G$ and nonempty subset $H$ of $G$ such that "$a \in H$ and $b \in H \rightarrow ab \in H$is satisfied but $H$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

Tell me whether my answer is correct or not?if I am wrong please correct me.my answer is $G = (R,+)$ and $H=(Z^+,+)$ the reason of that I chose it is eliminating the identity element.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks please tell me whether my reason is correct or not?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: even if you didn't eliminate the identity element, you still wouldn't have *inverses*; you could have taken $H$ to be $(\mathbb R^{\ge0},+)$

Comment: Yes, your reason is correct too.

Answer (score 4):

Your answer and reason are correct.

Your reason could be more complete (although this is not necessary): you have also excluded the inverses of the elements of $\Bbb{Z}^+$ under addition.